# Compute the Limiting Distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

> Consider the transition matrix
>
> $ P =   \begin{bmatrix} 1-p&p\\ q&1-q  \end{bmatrix}  $
>
> for general $2$-state Markov Chain $(0 \le p, q\le 1)$.
>
> - Find the limiting distribution (if it exists) if $p + q \ne 1$.

Using mathematical induction, it is solved using the following proof:

$
p^n = \frac{1}{p+q}  \begin{bmatrix}q&p\\q&p\end{bmatrix} + \frac{(1-p-q)^n}{p+q} \begin{bmatrix}p&-p\\-q&q\end{bmatrix} 
$

This is totally cumbersome.

Can this be solved in any other way like using $\pi (P-I) = 0$ and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I think induction works well as long as you don't make a dumb mistake on the matrix math (I did the first time I tried it!).

I apologize for the formatting!!  Still getting used to latex.

For the first term, we can show that it stays the same after being multiplied by the transition matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} q&p \\q&p \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1-p   & p \\ q & 1-q \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} q(1-p) + pq   & pq+p(1-q) \\  q(1-p) + pq   & pq+p(1-q) \end{bmatrix} $

$\begin{bmatrix} q&p \\q&p \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1-p   & p \\ q & 1-q \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  q-qp + pq   & pq+p-pq) \\ q-qp + pq   & pq+p-pq) \end{bmatrix} $

$\begin{bmatrix} q&p \\q&p \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1-p   & p \\ q & 1-q \end{bmatrix} =   \begin{bmatrix} q   & p \\ q   & p  \end{bmatrix}$

For the second term, it's a little tougher:

$\begin{bmatrix} p & -p \\ -q & q \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1-p & p \\  q & 1-q \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} p(1-p) - pq & p^2-p(1-q) \\ -q(1-p) -q^2 & -qp+q(1-q) \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} p & -p \\ -q & q \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1-p & p \\  q & 1-q \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} p(1-p-q) & -p(1-q-p) \\ -q(1-p-q) &  q(1-q-p) \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} p & -p \\ -q & q \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1-p & p \\  q & 1-q \end{bmatrix} = (1-p-q) 
\begin{bmatrix}
 p   & -p \\
 -q   & p 
\end{bmatrix}$

this creates the $(1-p-q)^{n+1}$ term